# How to scrape images from a website and display them on html file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping images from https://www.open2study.com/courses
I got all the image sources but dont know how to display the images (instead of links) on a table with 2 column ( one column for title and one for image) on a html file.Can expert help me out?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

titles = []
images = []

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.open2study.com/courses').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "courses_adblock_rollover"}):
    titles.append(i.h2.text)

for i in soup.find_all(
    'img', {
        'class': "image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}):
    images.append(i.get('src'))

with open('test.txt', "w") as f:
    for i in zip(titles, images):
        f.write(i[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore') +
                '\n'+i[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore') +
                '\n\n')

header = '<!doctyle html><html><head><title>My Title</title></head><body>'
body = '<table><thead><tr><th></th><th></th></tr>'

footer = '</table></body></html>'
img_tag = '<img src=,{}">'


with open('test.txt', 'r') as input, open('test.html', 'w') as output:
   output.write(header)
   output.write(body)

   for line in input:
       col1 = line.rstrip().split()
       col2 = line.rstrip().split()
       output.write('<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>\n'.format(col1, col2))

   output.write(footer)
```

Comment: Please clarify the scenerio `display the images`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have written already

Comment: your iterator is wrong...it is iterating one line each whereas you are considering it two lines i.e for col1 and col2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display images and titles in 2 column in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640792/display-images-and-titles-in-2-column-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty simple problem.try this one

```
for line in input:
    #ignore blank lines
    if line == '\n':
        continue
    #why were you spliting here?
    col1 = line.rstrip()
    #read next line
    col2 = next(input).rstrip()
    output.write('<tr><td>{}</td><td><img src="{}" style="width: 160px; height: 100px"></td></tr>\n'.format(col1, col2))
```

Comment: @ Saad Abdullah but how do i display the images? Your codes only dislays image source links

Comment: where should i insert img tag?

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, the images display all over the places instead of displaying in one column, and titles are in other column

Comment: this is exactly what you wanted...hope you can fix that by your own...have a nice day :)