# Display images and titles in 2 column in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I scraped all titles and image source links into a text file, then use the data from the text file to output a html file with 2 columns, one for images and one for titles.How to display clickable images, and display title and image in 2 column format? Here is what i have

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

titles = []
images = []
href  = []

r = urllib.urlopen('https://www.open2study.com/courses').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "courses_adblock_rollover"}):
    titles.append(i.h2.text)

for i in soup.find_all('img', {'class': "image-style-course-logo-subjects-block"}):
    images.append(i.get('src'))



with open('test.txt', "w") as f:
    for i in zip(titles, images):
        f.write(i[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore') + '\n'
                +i[1].encode('ascii', 'ignore') +
                '\n\n')

header = '<!doctyle html><html><head><title>My page</title></head><body>'
body = '<table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr>'

footer = '</table></body></html>'


with open('test.txt', 'r') as input, open('test.html', 'w') as output:
   output.write(header)
   output.write(body)

   for line in input:
    #ignore blank lines
       if line == '\n':
            continue

       col1 = line.rstrip()
       #read next line
       col2 = next(input).rstrip()
       output.write('<tr><td>{}</td><td><img src="{}" style="width: 160px;             height: 100px"></td></tr>\n\n'.format(col1, col2))
       output.write(footer)
```

Comment: What was wrong with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602951/how-to-scrape-images-from-a-website-and-display-them-on-html-file)?

Comment: The images and tittle are not displayed in 2 columns, and the images are not clickable

Comment: Or basic html.  Map it out in HTML first and then build that structure with code.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're making this scraping thing really difficult on yourself. It's easier to start with the largest element first, i.e. the whole course div, then pull information out of it later on.

This code give you the clickable images in the first column and titles of the courses in the second column.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

base_url = 'https://www.open2study.com'
r = urllib.urlopen(base_url + '/courses').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

courses = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "courses_adblock_start"})

encoding = "utf-8"
page_title = 'Ai Truong'
html_template = '<!doctyle html><html><head><title>{}</title><meta charset="{}" /></head><body>{}</body></html>'
table_template = '<table>{}</table>'
table_row_template = '<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>'
img_template = '<a href="{}"><img src="{}" width="160px;" alt="{}"></a>'

table_rows = ''
for c in courses:
    title = c.h2.text.encode(encoding)
    image = c.find('img', {'class': 'image-style-course-logo-subjects-block'}).get('src')
    href = c.parent.get('href')
    img_tag = img_template.format(base_url + href, image, title)
    table_rows += table_row_template.format(img_tag, title)

table_tag = table_template.format(table_rows)

with open('course-scrape.html', 'w') as html_out:
    html_out.write(html_template.format(page_title, encoding, table_tag))
```

#### Output

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: I run your codes and got this :   image = c.find('img', class_='image-style-course-logo-subjects-block').get('src')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I just ran it locally and that line works... I assume you are using the latest BeautifulSoup version? @Mina

Comment: I have issues with beautifulsoup running on my mac. Yes, i got the lastest version, but it only can run on python2

Comment: What if you do `image = c.find('img', {'class': 'image-style-course-logo-subjects-block'}).get('src')`

Comment: Awesome. Updated answer.

Comment: One more question, how do I save the scrape titles and src link to a source file?

Comment: Make some empty lists above the course loop, add that information to those lists as you loop over the courses, then write a new file after the loop with those lists